# About OpenGL Image format , what does GL driver do when transfering pixels to GPU

Tags: opengl, format, textures

When I, for example, try to transfer pixels with `glTextureSubImage1D`, I specify internalformat- GL_R3_G3_B2, format-GL_RGB , type-GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE_3_3_2, what does the single pixel final state in GPU memory look like? (3bit-f, 3bit-f, 2bit-f) or (32bit-f, 32bit-f, 32bit-f)?

Comment: What is `3bit-f`? A 3bit float? That doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm not sure if OpenGL even guarantees the exact memory layout on the GPU. For all you know, it has to behave like a 8-bit data with r3g3b2 layout when you access it. I'd assume that most drivers will also store it that way in GPU memory.

Comment: In full opengl not gles, the precision is always highest, right? so when i sample a texture which pixels format is GL_R3_G3_B2, what is the sampling process look like, it will convert the 3bit component to a 32bit-float component dynamically every time?  Or the pixel has been converted to a 32 bit-float component when it transfered to GPU memory?